# Silex controller not found

Tags: php, controller, silex

I'm new user of Silex framework and I have a little (huge for me) problem with registering route to controller. My controller can not be found by Silex.
Here is my tree of files:

[image]

My *composer.json* file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.3",
        "twig/twig": "^1.24",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Controller\\": "web/"
        }
    }
}
```

My *index.php* file in web directory:

```
<?php

// web/index.php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider;

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug']=TRUE;

$app->get('/','HomeController::index');

$app->run();
```

and *HomeController.php* file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Oskar
 * Date: 2016-02-07
 * Time: 02:27
 */
namespace web\Controller{
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Silex\Application;

    use Silex\ControllerCollection;
    class HomeController
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return 'Hello Controller';
        }
    }
}
```

My error:

[image]

Regards.

Comment: you've to specify the complete namespace of your controller

Comment: I changed my namespace to this: namespace web\Controller\HomeController . I have same error.

Comment: try to follow the documentation as specified here http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/organizing_controllers.html

Comment: You're missusing the namespaces. Your controller is in the *Controller* namespace and you're using *web\Controller*. See your composer psr-4 key: ```"Controller\\": "web/"``` you're telling composer to load the *Controller* namespace inside the web folder, but the you define instead the *web/Controller* one. In your controller just use the *Controller* namespace

Comment: IMHO, you should not place your controller inside the public web folder, it would be better to have a *src* folder at the same level of web and vendor directories.

Comment: @mTorres I changed my tree of files, composer.json and namespace used in HomeController. My tree: http://prntscr.com/a0ivof HomeController: http://prntscr.com/a0iuw9
My composer.json: http://prntscr.com/a0iv4s and index.php: http://prntscr.com/a0ivag

Comment: You are missusing the namespace again, in the *index.php* file now you just need to call the matching like so ```$app->get('/','Controller\HomeController::index');``` the *src* part shouldn't be there.

Comment: I sent only one picture but i tried many ways to change this route. http://prntscr.com/a0jam2 I have same problem.

Comment: @mTorres i tried to change psr-4 to psr-0 in my composer.json and it is working now... Can you explain it for me? I know that psr-4 is better to use in project but i do not know why MY project did not worked with psr-4.

Comment: You've tried so many variation that is hard to tell, it should definitely work with psr4. Anyway, now it's working :-) PS: Did you run a ```composer dump-autoload``` everytime you've changed the psr key? Maybe you didn't in some variation.

Comment: Yes, of course i did. Without a result :/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should use below line i hope it will help you

```
use Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface;


 class HomeController implements ControllerProviderInterface {
```